# Spark history server filter jobs by user id or time

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

My spark yarn cluster is used by many users and there are numerous jobs in spark history server. It takes lot of time to paginate through spark history server to locate my job. I couldn't find any option to filter jobs by user id on spark wiki [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api).

I was wondering, are there any ways to select list of jobs submitted by particular user? or during particular time windows? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ***yarn*** you can rely on yarn to list and filter you application

```
yarn application -list | grep -i spark | grep hdpuser
```

should list your spark application by hdpuser. 
Also on the YARN web UI you can see all your jobs and you can filter by different criteria ([yarn commands](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YarnCommands.html)).

Using the REST API, on the path */applications/[app-id]/environment* you have the environment details for you spark application(It is only available for 2.2 spark version). Use the property *user.name* and it's value should be the user name that started the spark job.

Take a look on the listed environment properties on the spark web UI on port 4040 to see all the available properties.

Comment: yeah, currently I have been following this process only and challenge here is, have to list jobs using yarn then query spark history server. In my organisation infra team has disabled yarn access through UI/rest and in order to login to production cluster there is lengthy process. But we do have direct access to spark history server UI.

Comment: Got it! See my edit. I think that there are a lot of useful information on the rest api exposed

Comment: Thanks, it make sense ! again thing is that when cluster is shared among multiple users and jobs you would not get fixed fixed port number, the 4040 is might have been assigned to another job and you get next available port greater than 4040. So port number is not certain in this case.

Comment: True, I just gave you an example of how the properties are named and that are listed on the spark web ui. But you don't use that port when you query with the rest api. You just use the port for the spark job history server, which will be only one.

Comment: My question is around that problem only, to query spark history server you would need application id and in my case finding out application id process is bit cumbersome through yarn command.